# limit middle div width to child div width

Tags: html, css

I have nested divs like so:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

The third div contains dynamic content - so I don't know it's dimensions.

What I want is the second div to take the width of the third div and not of the first div which is a lot bigger.

So in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bBusJ/), I want the border to enclose the green square.
Is this possible with css only? if so, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/bBusJ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `float: left;` in the second class. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

.second {
  float: left;
}

or

.second {
  display: inline-block; //not working on ie7
}

Answer (score 0):

Actually `div` is a block level element so you can give the `display:inline-block` to **second div** and than it will take the **third** `div` **width & height** vic-versa...

**CSS**

```
.first
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: yellow;
}

.second
{
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}

.third
{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/DIKwygp8)**